# HTML, CSS, or JavaScript first? How should I write my code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been learning web development for the past few months now, I have really been enjoying it a lot but I have started my own projects just to mess around and see what I really know.

With my most recent project I have been building my portfolio page, the way I currently write my code goes like this: I write all my HTML first so I have the layout of the page, after I have all of that is written, I then go into my CSS and style everything. Then I go and do JavaScript.

My question is this, is this an efficient way of writing code? Should I keep doing it this way? Or should I write some HTML, style it, go back and forth, then move onto JavaScript? Is there a more efficient way of how you write code?

Comment: I'd flip back and forth between HTML and CSS to get the layout down first, and *then* start adding JS, unless you're using JS for layouting too, then you'll have to jump right in with all 3. CSS might force you to change your markup, so I definitely wouldn't write *all* the HTML first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is opinion based so there is not a correct answer.

Some may like to write first the html and after that css, others like to write small parts html and after that the css that comes with that particular html, so you are writing step by step your website.

Take a look at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/ for questions like this.

However, to answer your question: I like to write small parts of the application step by step. So, First write HTML and CSS for my Navigation for instance. After I have written the HTML and CSS I like to write the JS of that particular component.

The reason I like this so much is because it's close to the principles of Scrum where you deliver each time a working piece of software instead of piece of code that isn't working at all. So I prefer a website where you have only a working navigation bar above a whole website where nothing is working at all.

Comment: Why should questions like this be on meta?

Answer (score -1):

Subjective question however the way I was taught was develop for mobile first HTML and CSS. Once the layout for that is done then you can focus on the interaction using JavaScript and stuff like that.

However, I don't really use .html files anymore since I'm developing multiple pages I instead use .PHP because of the includes. However, if it was a single page then I would use HTML.

On the flip side however, I also got bored with CSS and realized I needed a faster way so I switched to a CSS processor like Sass which makes writing CSS a lot quicker and more efficient.

Comment: Its a bit naive to use PHP for the includes. If thats your motivation for using PHP exstension why not use a PHP framework right ahead?

Comment: I don't use PHP for just includes. I use it for other things as well such as server-side validation for forms and retrieving data. I'm currently learning Laravel so I haven't been able to fully use it yet in my skill set. I've been writing my own custom PHP in the meantime.

Comment: Nice job. I like the Laravel framework, you should learn more about the blade files. But, I don't see a reason for using PHP when you can use JS for validation of forms? Also, it depends on the job. I would not use PHP if the job is just a simple website becuase PHP is always more loading time than JS (client vs server).

Comment: You are very correct. Their is no point using PHP if it's just a simple one page website. Although, on forms I was taught that having server-side and client side validation for forms is always recommended simply because the users can have JavaScript disabled in there browser and bypass your form unless you have the input required attribute. But if it's just a one page, client side with the attribute and JavaScript is good enough.